# @Autowired is not working in quartz job class

Tags: java, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler

I'm sending post request to run() method class name is ScheduleGame. This class the creates the Quartz RAM based job and triggers.

```
@Component
public class ScheduleGame {
    Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ScheduleGame.class);

    public String run(String jobName, String jobGroup, Class jobClass, String jobTrigger, String cronExp) throws Exception {
        try {
            isJobExist(jobGroup, jobName);


            log.info("------- Initializing -------------------");
            // First we must get a reference to a scheduler
            SchedulerFactory sf = new StdSchedulerFactory();
            Scheduler sched = sf.getScheduler();
            log.info("------- Initialization Complete --------");

            log.info("------- Scheduling Jobs ----------------");
            // job1 will only fire once at date/time "ts"
            JobDetail job = newJob(jobClass).withIdentity(jobName, jobGroup).build();
            CronTrigger trigger = newTrigger().withIdentity(jobTrigger, jobGroup).withSchedule(
                    cronSchedule(cronExp).withMisfireHandlingInstructionFireAndProceed()).build();


            // schedule it to run!
            Date ft = sched.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
            log.info(job.getKey() + " will run at: " + ft + " and repeat: " + trigger.getNextFireTime() + " times, every "
                    + trigger.getExpressionSummary() + " seconds");
            sched.start();
            log.info(sched.getSchedulerName());
            return "Game Created and Scheduled, it will run at: " + ft;

        } catch (CustomException e) {
            throw new Exception(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

my job class is

```
@Component
public class Job implements InterruptableJob {

    private static Logger _log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Job.class);
    private JobKey _jobKey = null;
    @Autowired
    private Results results;

    /*public void setResults(Results results) {
        this.results = results;
    }*/

    /**
     * Empty constructor for job initialization
     */
    public Job() {
    }

    /**
     * <p>
     * Called by the <code>{@link org.quartz.Scheduler}</code> when a
     * <code>{@link org.quartz.Trigger}</code> fires that is associated with
     * the <code>Job</code>.
     * </p>
     *
     * @throws JobExecutionException if there is an exception while executing the job.
     */
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context)
            throws JobExecutionException {
        SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);
        // This job simply prints out its job name and the
        // date and time that it is running
        _jobKey = context.getJobDetail().getKey();
        _log.info("Job Name: "+ _jobKey.getName() +" Job Group: "+ _jobKey.getGroup()+" SimpleJob says: " + _jobKey + " executing at " + new Date());

        results.lotteryResults(_jobKey.getName(),_jobKey.getGroup());

    }

    @Override
    public void interrupt() throws UnableToInterruptJobException {
        _log.info("---" + _jobKey + "  -- INTERRUPTING --");
    }
}
```

Exception is:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at agaming.casino.lottery.handler.Job.execute(Job.java:54)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573)
.19:24:00.001 [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-10] ERROR org.quartz.core.ErrorLogger - Job (SampleJob.Sample Job threw an exception. 
org.quartz.SchedulerException: Job threw an unhandled exception.
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:213)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at agaming.casino.lottery.handler.Job.execute(Job.java:54)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
    ... 1 common frames omitted
```

When trigger fire on scheduled time the job is running fine if there is no @Autowired followed by my service class. But I've t @Autowired my services to do other business functions on job fires.

How to @Autowired my services in Quartz job class

I'm using Spring Boot

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/37086715/2469484

Comment: Thanks a lot @srinivas, you saved my day. i just placed the code snippet in my ScheduleGame class it worked fine..