# Unable to inject service in Apache isis quartz

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, isis

I am using quartz in my apache isis project for scheduling. I have a class MyJob which implements org.quartz.Job and it has method execute which is called when scheduler triggers at given time.

My problem is, I have a class `DemoService` and it has a method `showDemo()` which I want to call from the execute method.
But when the scheduler runs, it throws Null Pointer Exception at `demoService.showDemo()`.

I have not been able to inject any service in that class. It always gives NPE. How can I inject a service into the `MyJob` class?

Here is the code:-

```
public class MyJob implements Job {

    @Inject
    DemoService demoService;

    public MyJob() {

    }

    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
        demoService.showDemo();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest approach is to put the logic you want to run in a subclass of [AbstractIsisSessionTemplate](http://isis.apache.org/guides/ugbtb/ugbtb.html#_ugbtb_headless-access_AbstractIsisSessionTemplate), and then instantiate and execute it from your quartz job.

This technique is used by the Incode Platform's quartz job to run background commands, see [here](https://github.com/incodehq/incode-platform/blob/master/modules/spi/command/impl/src/main/java/org/isisaddons/module/command/dom/BackgroundCommandExecutionFromBackgroundCommandServiceJdo.java); the [quartz module](http://platform.incode.org/modules/ext/quartz/ext-quartz.html) shows this from the quartz perspective (which I think you already have figured out).

HTH
Dan

Answer (score 0):

Try this [NullPointerException while deploying Quartz in Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37075328/nullpointerexception-while-deploying-quartz-in-spring-boot/37086715#37086715)

You need to use SpringBeanJobFactory to create Job with Spring's autowired beans.

class AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory extends SpringBeanJobFactory implements ApplicationContextAware {
    private transient AutowireCapableBeanFactory beanFactory;

```
public void setApplicationContext(final ApplicationContext context) {
    beanFactory = context.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
}

@Override
public Object createJobInstance(final TriggerFiredBundle bundle) throws Exception {
   final Object job = super.createJobInstance(bundle);
   beanFactory.autowireBean(job);  //the magic is done here
   return job;
}
```

}
And then when you do

```
SchedulerFactory schedFact = new org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory();
scheduler = schedFact.getScheduler();

AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory autowiringSpringBeanJobFactory = new AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory();
autowiringSpringBeanJobFactory.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
scheduler.setJobFactory(autowiringSpringBeanJobFactory);
```